# Spring MVC @Response Body XML has extra <string> tags - why?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have configured things as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "com.whatever.api")
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter =
            new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();

        // List<MediaType> mediaType = new ArrayList<>();
        // mediaType.add(MediaType.TEXT_XML);

        XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        // xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaType);
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);

        return xmlConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter() {
        return new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller() {
        return new XStreamMarshaller();
    }

    // added to support files in body of add document request
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

And here is the method that returns the XML which is to go in the response:

```
    // @RequestMapping(value = "/getDocuments", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE })
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDocuments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String
statementList(@RequestParam("doctype") String doctype,
    @RequestParam("bin") String bin,
    @RequestParam("br") String br,
    @RequestParam("mid") String mid,
    @RequestParam("passwd") String passwd,
    @RequestParam("dates") String dates,
    HttpServletRequest request) {

    String xmlResponse;
    RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandlerImpl(systemProperties, null, tableDataDao);
    xmlResponse = requestHandler.getStatements(bin, br, mid, passwd, dates);
    System.out.println("xmlResponse=" + xmlResponse);

    return xmlResponse;
}
```

The xmlResponse String value is correct XML, exactly like I want it.  My problem is that the response ends up looking like this:

```
    <string><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a bunch of correct, but unformatted, XML here></string>
```

The clear difficulty is the "" tags which appear to come from nowhere.  As can be seen from what I've commented out I've tried to set the MediaType (to TEXT_PLAIN, TEXT_XML, and APPLICATION_XML) which doesn't get rid of the extraneous  tags no matter what I choose.

It ends up being rather important that the XML in the response is correct, just like in the xmlResponse String value.  Is there a setting I'm missing  or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of kuporific, I've solved the problem.

I had to add a converter as shown here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "com.roler.api")
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    // added to support plain text Spring responses
    @Bean
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    }
...
```

I then had to specify plain text as in here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDocuments", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody public String statementList(...)
```

...and it works without needing an HttpServletResponse object.

Thanks again for your help, and hopefully someone can find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are converting the response into an XML `String` yourself in the `requestHandler`. However, the `requestHandler` should be returning a business object, and `statementList` should be return that object, rather than `String`.

See the [@RequestMapping Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

> The following return types are supported for handler methods:
>
> - [@ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) annotated methods (Servlet-only) for access to the Servlet response HTTP contents. The return value will be converted to the response stream using [message converters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html).

Since `statementList` returns `String`, the message converters are converting it to XML (which is why you're seeing your response wrapped in `<string>...</string>`).

Comment: I've tried this now with a simple object, and it does return the XML version of that object but with the fully-qualified namespace of that object's class as tags wrapping it.  What I want to know, then -- if it's possible -- is how to suppress this behaviour.

Comment: @SCRawl I think this behavior comes from `XStreamMarshaller`, and there are other XML marshallers that you could use (some JAXB ones), but it'll take me some time to confirm all this and give you a meaningful response.

Comment: Just to be clear, the use case here is to simply return a String which is already formatted as XML (which was generated by a completely separate, external process).  I'm not trying to represent an object as XML.  Also:  thank you for your help so far.

Comment: To explain further:  when I disable the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (and any other converters) and set the "produces" to MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE I get exactly the result I want.  With this converter enabled, Spring is treating my XML String like badly-formed JSON if I don't specify an XML converter, and it's treating it like an object I want to serialize if I do.  My goal would seem to be finding a converter that doesn't behave like this.

Comment: @SCRawl Perhaps you've considered this already, but what about putting the XML into the `response` object yourself? That is, add a `HttpServletResponse` parameter to the `statementList` method and call `response.getOutputStream.print(xmlResponse)`.

Comment: This approach works, but is suboptimal; the ideal way to do so is within the Spring framework, if possible.  But it's a fine suggestion, thanks for making it.